# Текущее время на странице сайта

Tags: html, php, javascript

Интересно, как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "дата" отображалось время и дата?

Comment: Именно при нажатии?

Comment: Откуда время нужно брать? с клиента(что лично мне кажется почти всегда неуместным, т.к. время у человека под носом вне зависимости от ОС) или с сервера?
Второй конечно предпочтительней. Реализацию первого Вам уже описали, а вот второй я бы сделал на js + сервер. То есть динамически (ajax) обращался бы к скрипту, который бы возвращал строку с текущими датой и временем. 

Answer (score 3):

Текущее время и дата клиента:

```
<html>        
    <body>
        <input type=button value="Show Time" onclick="alert(new Date())">
    </body>    
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

С помощью `date()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>        
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getDate()
{
    var date = new Date();
    var hours = date.getHours();
    var minutes = date.getMinutes();
    var seconds = date.getSeconds();
    //По надобности условие ниже повторить с minutes и hours
    if(seconds < 10)
    {
        seconds = '0' + seconds;
    }
    document.getElementById('timedisplay').innerHTML = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
}
setInterval(getDate, 0);
</script>
<div id="timedisplay"></div>
</body>    
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
function fulltime () {
var time=new Date();
document.clock.full.value=time.toLocaleString();
setTimeout('fulltime()',500)
}
-->
</script><!-- информер даты и времени на сайт | число месяц год время  --><a href="http://zagd.ru/node/43"><form name="clock"><input size="30" name="full"></form><script language="JavaScript">
fulltime ();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Функция вывода даты и времени форматом: 18 октября 17 13:41:58

```
function setPageTime() {
var currentDateObj = document.getElementById('current-date');
if (currentDateObj) {
    var monthList = new Array('января', 'февраля', 'марта', 'апреля', 'мая', 'июня', 'июля', 
        'августа', 'сентября', 'октября', 'ноября', 'декабря');
    var currDate = new Date();
    var m = monthList[currDate.getMonth()];
    var s = check_zero(currDate.getDate()) + ' ' + m + ' ' + Math.round(currDate.getFullYear()%1000) + ' ' +
        check_zero(currDate.getHours()) + ':' + check_zero(currDate.getMinutes()) + ':' + 
        check_zero(currDate.getSeconds());
    currentDateObj.innerHTML = s;
}
setTimeout('setPageTime(1000)');
```

Html блок выводящий дату и время:

```
<div id="current-date"></div>
```